# Using Emit IL with internal classes?

Tags: c#, performance, reflection, instantiation, reflection.emit

I have a base class which has an embedded List that can be used by all child classes to return a sorted collection.

I had been using `Activator.CreateInstance()`, but this is TERRBILY slow compared to a simple new() function.

I found a way to use Emit IL to do this nearly as fast as new(), but if my classes aren't public, I get a `MethodAccessException` error. This seems to be common.

Is there a way around this?

Code to generate classes here:
http://codeblocks.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FasterActivator%20Sample

Code being used with the above here:

```
public static List<T> SortedCollection<T>(SPListItemCollection items, ListSortType sortType, List<Vote> votes) where T : IVotable
{
    var returnlist = new List<T>();  
    var functionCreator = FastActivator.GenerateFunc<Func<SPListItem, List<Vote>, T>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++) { returnlist.Add(functionCreator(items[i], votes)); }

    //Old code here
    //Type genericType = typeof(T);
    //for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++) { returnlist.Add((T)Activator.CreateInstance(genericType, new object[] { items[i], votes })); }

    switch (sortType)
    {
        case ListSortType.Hot:
            returnlist.Sort((p1, p2) => p2.HotScore.CompareTo(p1.HotScore));
            break;
        case ListSortType.Top:
            returnlist.Sort((p1, p2) => p2.VoteTotal.CompareTo(p1.VoteTotal));
            break;
        case ListSortType.Recent:
            returnlist.Sort((p1, p2) => p2.CreatedDate.CompareTo(p1.CreatedDate));
            break;
        }
        return returnlist;
    }

    //Usage
    //Post : BaseClass which has above method
    return Post.SortedCollection<Post>(listItems,sortType,votes);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [DynamicMethod Constructor (String, Type, Type[], Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z84bd3st.aspx) method to generate a method associated with the class who's members you want access to.

The generated method will have full access to *all members* in the type you associate it with, and all internal methods and members the class would have access to in its module.